# How do I extend my /var partition? (Or whichever lets me install more with apt)

Tags: apt, partitioning

[image of my gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZLXK.png)

How can I extend /var? I think thats what I need more storage in to install more with apt. I am using VMWare.